# how to connect android with phpmyadmin

Tags: php, android, mysql, phpmyadmin

How to connect android with phpmyadmin?
I used Android Studio and WAMP server, I searched relative information, but I could not know how to pick out which one is useful for me. 
I could insert data into mysql with php.file, and query the data from mysql.  But I don't know how to connect Android with Phpmyadmin, how to upload/ download from mysql.

Comment: There is a google library called 'volley' available for connecting your android app to php files which will connect to phpMyAdmin. http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html Just use this library for calling phpFiles and you can send data to php file for inserting into your mysql and can also parse the data from php while which is fetched from mysql. For sample use of volley you can also follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect Android phone and Computer to the same network
2. In mobile browser, type the IP address of the computer with port number
3. Enter phpMyAdmin credentials and access WAMP projects

Comment: 1. Computer creates a wireless Network, then mobile add into it?

Comment: computers' wireless network might not be visible to android devices, I suggest to connect both to common network and adjust network sharing settings accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Please change http://localhost/.... with http://10.0.2.2/.... in your urls configurations

**EDIT :** if you use a real Android device, search the IP adress of your computer in your router main page configuration and replace localhost by this ip adress, it will work

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is not a database, it's a web-based application from which you can perform administrative tasks on a MySQL (or MariaDB) database.

If you're really trying to connect to phpMyAdmin, just enter the URL in to the web browser. https://example.com/phpmyadmin or https://192.0.2.52/phpmyadmin or something similar.

However, if you're trying to get an application on your Andriod device to talk to a MySQL database hosted somewhere else, you're not going to want to connect directly to it, you'll want an API running on the database machine to authenticate, handle incoming requests, and return appropriate responses. You can code that in PHP if you want, or whatever programming language suits you, then you access that URL from your Android app.

Comment: I wrote code in PHP to visit phpMyAdmin, then set PHP file's path as URL, like "10.0.2.2:8080/androidconnect/login.php", is it right ? However, how do Android phone distinguish the URL and visit?